# codeception: running multiple sql dump files

Tags: mysql, codeception

I'm looking for help or documentation if it is possible to dump multiple sql dump files using codeception, and use a configuration like this:

```
modules:
    config:
        - Db:
            dsn: 'sqlite:./var/cache/test/test.sqlite'
            user: ''
            password: ''
    =>      dump: 'tests/_data/*.sql'   <=
            populate: true
            cleanup: true
            reconnect: true
```

Answer (score 5):

You can now do it with

```
- Db:
    dsn: 'sqlite:./var/cache/test/test.sqlite'
    user: ''
    password: ''
    dump: 
        - 'tests/_data/d1.sql'  
        - 'tests/_data/d2.sql'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible straight out of the box. 
An alternative would be to combine the dumps into 1 dump file.

You can also have a look at my answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499975/codeception-acceptance-tests-within-database-transaction-on-mysql/44504577#44504577), maybe it can be helpful for you.